# Get the platform key from .apk file to sign and generate another .apk file

Tags: android, keystore

I have a .apk file. And I want to get the platform key (with .jks or .keystore format)from this .apk to sign another .apk. Is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: What have you searched/tried so far?

Comment: Maher is correct, it is not possible to extract the private key from a signed apk file

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to sign  APK by retrieving all data necessary for signing from another APK ... answer is NO.. you need to get that keystone to sign same or another APK.